# get value of checkbox in symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to get the value of checkbox (checked or not), but the checkedbox not added to the form type. this is an example

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="smsflash">
```

I ask if there are a possibility to get the value of the checkedbox in the controller or not, and how?

Comment: If I understood correctly this checbox is not a part of the form and you render it manually. Is there a reason for it? You are able to get the result from global variables like `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: in fact, you understand correctly what i mean, I wanna to get the value of this checkbox beaucause when it's checked i should get the value of other field which are a part of the form

Comment: Then I would consider making the checkbox part of the whole form.

Comment: the checkbox is a part of the form but not in the formtype, just added to the form

Comment: why not add the checkbox into the formtype, just set it as mapped=false so it doesn't get associated to the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a bit late now, but my experience may relate to your issue, or may help someone else with a similar issue.

In my case, the checkbox is added to the FormType, but would present the same I imagine if added outside of the FormType.

I'm using the form to handle a REST API request, and the checkbox is one of the fields. When the form is submitted, the header includes `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` so I can handle it with a Symfony form.

The issue with this is the form values are submitted as strings (including checkbox values). On the Symfony side, it expects that if the checkbox property exists - it's a 'truthy' value, if it doesn't exist, the checkbox is false. However because the checkbox value can be submitted as the string "false" through the API form - this equates to true - so the value is always true no matter if the checkbox is checked or not.

One way to handle this (but may limit re-use of the FormType) is to change the checkbox type from 'checkbox' to 'text' in the Form Builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('my_checkbox', 'text', array('error_bubbling' => true,'required' => false))
        ...
```

Then processing the form (and getting the Checkbox value)

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $myObject);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
    if($data->getMyCheckbox() === "false") {
        $myObject->setMyCheckbox(false);
    } else {
        $myObject->setMyCheckbox(true);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Set name to input

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="smsflash" name="button_name">
```

and then in the controller

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
//..
public function exampleAction(Request $request, $id){
    //..
    $inputValue = $request->get("button_name");
    //..
}
```