# How to enable a field when a checkbox is checked in php Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

I have a somewhat tricky scenario (for me), and I don't fully get how to do this.

An order is created and assigned to a supervisor for approval. The supervisor approve or disapprove the order by a click of a button. Sometimes the supervisor need to send the order for a second approval. To do this, before the supervisor approve the order he need to check a checkbox 'require second approval'. When that checkbox is checked a hidden field gets visible where the supervisor can choose a second user for approval.

That being said, how can I;

1. Get a checkbox in Symfony to toggle a field to be hidden or not, and
2. How can I check with PHP the Symfony way (if I can say it like that) when that checkbox is checked or not to update a status for the order. If the checkbox is checked -> means require second approval -> means 'partly approved' as status. If not checked -> means second approval not required -> means -> 'approved' as status. Note; the checkbox value is not stored in the database, or is it better to do so?

I really hope this is clear enough. Please, I need help, I don't know everything about Symfony yet. I started learning it in January.

Thank you in advance!

---

**Update:** I think I've found something to get me in a right direction; [get value of checkbox in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34902603/6580995)

Comment: Does your update mean this is solved..? Or do you still have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions here.

First about the checkbox :
You can have a checkbox not being stored in database. Use the property `mapped` in your form type : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped

Second, about displaying an optional field : 
There are many ways to do it.

One way would be to set this field in your form type, make it hidden by setting its type to "hidden" (2nd parameter of the `add()` function on the builder), add a javascript listener on the checkbox and update the type attribute of your field accordingly. this is the fast way.

One other way would be to use form listener/subscriber. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

in both ways, be sure your "second approval supervisor" property is nullable in your Order entity, because this field is optional.